# Cannot have Memo, OLE, or Hyperlink Object Fields in aggregate argument (BookNumber)

Tags: c#, ado.net

Im trying to get the max number of bookname column.

```
sql = "Select Max(BookNumber) From books";
        using (System.Data.IDbCommand cmd = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(sql, con))
        {
            object result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            bn.Text = Convert.ToString(result);
            if (bn.Text == "")
            {
                bn.Text = "0";
            }
            int zxc = Convert.ToInt32(bn.Text);
            zxc += 1;
            bn.Text =  Convert.ToString(zxc);
            da.Fill(dt);    
        }
```

Where i am doing wrong.

Comment: So, what is your question? What is not working exactly? You get any exception or error  message? This query works on your database manager? And you don't need to convert your integer to string (I assume your `BookNumber` column is numeric), just cast to int and compare it with `0`.

Comment: Cannot have Memo, OLE, or Hyperlink Object Fields in aggregate argument (BookNumber)
This is the error im getting from the line "ojbect result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();"

Comment: What is the error message _exactly_?

Comment: This the error. 

Cannot have Memo, OLE, or Hyperlink Object Fields in aggregate argument (BookNumber)

in line object result = cmd.executescalar();

Comment: The field type of BookNumber is longtext. And the booknumbers are 001,002, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Have you already looked up for the object structure you get in result?

As i understood, you want to get the book with the highest "number", so why dont you have a select like

*SELECT (asterisk) FROM books ORDER BY Booknumber*

So you will be able to find all books with the highest book number.

You should anyway use more significant variable names and provide more context info.

Hope it helped

Comment: as you can see, i want to get the highest booknumber then retrieve it. After retrieving it, this will happen..  
     int zxc = Convert.ToInt32(bn.Text);
            zxc += 1;
            bn.Text =  Convert.ToString(zxc);

Get the highest book number then add 1